# Need help whit my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I'm new to JavaScript and I have a problem with my code that I can't solve :(

```
 $(".kupongobjekt").append(text + ",");
 arrayHolder = $(".kupongobjekt").text;
 splitted = arrayHolder.split(",");
 numArray = splitted.sort(sortNumber);
 newest = numArray.toString();
 $(".kupongobjekt").text(newest);
```

That doesn't work at the moment.

arrayholder has a div that contains "4,5,3,3,2,8,9," but if I take `arrayHolder = "4,5,3,3,2,8,9,";` then it works. But without calling it in it doesn't work.

Ok, I know my english is bad but I hope you guys understand what my problem is :)

Comment: Java != Javascript. Please read the tag's description  when you add them.

Comment: There is `.text()` not `.text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, `text()` is a function:

```
$(".kupongobjekt").text;
```

should be

```
$(".kupongobjekt").text();
```